# Assignment vs if not equal to then assign... Swift being the language I care most about

Tags: swift, performance, if-statement, variable-assignment

I have some code that will get ran every so often. As far as performance goes, is there any difference between the following to satements, and if so, which one is faster?

```
num = 4
```

vs

```
if num != 4 {
    num = 4
}
```

I understand the difference is probably minimal, but I have had this question run through my mind on occasion. Also I would be interested in the closely related questions to this that might use a `Bool` or `String` instead of an `Int`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first one is faster for sure, because the processor has to do 1 instruction, which takes 1 clock cycle. In the second one there is at least 1 instruction or more (Comparison and optional assignment).

Assuming we have this code:

```
var x = 0
x = 4
```

Here are the important lines of the assembly (`swiftc -emit-assembly`):

```
    movq    $0, __Tv4test3numSi(%rip)  // Assigns 0 to the variable
    movq    $4, __Tv4test3numSi(%rip)  // Assigns 4 to the variable
```

As you can see, a single instruction is needed

And with this code:

```
var x = 0
if x != 4 {
    x = 4
}
```

Assembly:

```
    movq    $0, __Tv4test3numSi(%rip) // Assign 0 to the variable
    cmpq    $4, __Tv4test3numSi(%rip) // Compare variable with 4
    je  LBB0_4                        // If comparison was equal, jump to LBB0_4
    movq    $4, __Tv4test3numSi(%rip) // Otherwise set variable to 4
LBB0_4:
    xorl    %eax, %eax                // Zeroes the eax register (standard for every label)
```

As you can see, the second one uses either 3 instructions (when already equal to 4) or 4 instructions (when not equal 4).

It was clear to me from the beginning, but the assembly nicely demonstrates that the second one can't be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the assembly! Would this be the case with high level objects as well for the most part? I know that that question is super hard to answer wholeisticalxy, but I am fine with a more often than not answer.

Comment: @Sethmr Yes, every object is just a pointer, which is just a number. Of course if a struct/class has their own equality implementation, it's gonna be slower. Basically every assignment is just 1 operation, which is the minimum amount for the processor to do any thing at all, it can't be faster than that

Comment: I was taught in school that anything dealing with memory is automatically slower than if not dealing with memory, but I guess all the variables I am using would already be stored in cache at that point?

Comment: @Sethmr When you assign an object, only the pointer gets assigned. If you have a big struct, yes, the memory gets copied, but unless your struct is abnormally big, copying is still faster I think. You could experiment some more with this, view the assembly when using an object or a big struct to find out more

Comment: I believe you answered my question as good as I'm going to get. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3):

It's faster for me to read "num = 4". About three times faster. That's what I care about. You are attempting a microoptimisation of very dubious value, so I would be really worried if I saw someone writing that kind of code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this check

```
if num != 4 { ... }
```

if faster than an assignment

```
num = 4
```

### Scenario #1

So if most of the times `num` is **equals** to `4` you should skip the useless assignment and use this code

```
if num != 4 {
    num = 4
}
```

### Scenario #2

On the other hand if most of the times `num` is different from `4` you could remove the check and juts go with the assignment

```
num = 4
```